# How to edit and delete array objects with angular using components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, components

I created a table from array objects using angular components, also added ability to add new object, now i need to make a way to edit and delete these objects on a separate component in the same `<app>` html tag. Sorry if this is confusing i'm pretty new to all this.
Here is the code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzGqdR?editors=1010 
html and js

```
         <html ng-app="myApp">

      <head>
          <title>AngularJS</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8"/> 
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>
          <app></app>
      </body>

      </html>


angular.module('myApp', []);

        angular.module('myApp')

            .component('app', {
                template: `
                    <ma-input on-insert="$ctrl.insert(value)"></ma-input>
                    <hr>
                    <ma-table model="$ctrl.radars"></ma-table>
                    <ma-edit model="$ctrl.radars"></ma-edit>
                `,
                controller: AppCtrl
            })

            .component('maInput', {
                template: `
                    <label>Number: </label><input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.number">
                    <label>Distance: </label><input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.distance">
                    <label>Time: </label><input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.time">
                    <button ng-click="$ctrl.add()">add</button>
                    `,
                bindings: { 
                    onInsert: '&' 
                }, 
                controller: InputCtrl     
            })

            .component('maTable', {
                template: `
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Number</td>
                        <td>Distance (m)</td>
                        <td>Time (s)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="r in $ctrl.model">
                        <td>{{ r.number }}</td>
                        <td>{{ r.distance }}</td>
                        <td>{{ r.time }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $ctrl.speed(r) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                `,
                bindings: { model: '<' },
                controller: TableCtrl
            })


            function AppCtrl() {
                var ctrl = this;
                ctrl.radars = [
                    {number: 'ABC001', distance: 5000, time: 120},
                    {number: 'ZUK253', distance: 5000, time: 145},
                    {number: 'LRS852', distance: 5000, time: 150}
                ];
                ctrl.insert = function(newitem) {
                    ctrl.radars.push(newitem);    
                }
            }

            function InputCtrl() {
                var ctrl = this;
                //ctrl.number = '';
                ctrl.add = function() {
                    if (!ctrl.number || !ctrl.distance || !ctrl.time) return;
                    ctrl.onInsert({value: {
                        number: ctrl.number, 
                        distance: ctrl.distance, 
                        time: ctrl.time}
                    });
                }
            }

            function TableCtrl() {
                var ctrl = this;
                ctrl.speed = function(a) {
                    return Math.round(a.distance / a.time * 3.6);
                }
            }
```

`